# SVG animation is not showing on web

Tags: svg, css-animations

I've set up an svg animation in codepen that ran perfectly fine, however when importing over to my php file, the animation doesn't seem to be showing as it should.

The only difference is that the one I've placed in my php consists of an additional position-absolute class but I don't see why that whould affect it in any sense?

```css
body {
  background: #E34B2E;
}
svg {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.flightpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
animation: flight 3s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes flight {
  0%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}
.flightdashed {
  stroke-dasharray: 8;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 110.89 274.65">
  <path class="flightpath" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"d="M.5,0s.88,39.75,54.06,89.52c21.25,19.89,57.14,44.95,44.59,78.81a51.73,51.73,0,0,1-15.34,21.08c-5.15,4.37-11.09,8-17.67,9.49s-13.84.76-19.47-3c-8-5.3-11.37-16.13-9-25.4s10-16.75,18.85-20.3,19-3.47,28.25-1.07c43.36,11.22,22.3,73.81,4.28,97.73-10.46,13.87-25.71,24.65-42.88,27.27"/>
  <path class="flightdashed" fill="none" stroke="#E34B2E" stroke-width="4"d="M.5,0s.88,39.75,54.06,89.52c21.25,19.89,57.14,44.95,44.59,78.81a51.73,51.73,0,0,1-15.34,21.08c-5.15,4.37-11.09,8-17.67,9.49s-13.84.76-19.47-3c-8-5.3-11.37-16.13-9-25.4s10-16.75,18.85-20.3,19-3.47,28.25-1.07c43.36,11.22,22.3,73.81,4.28,97.73-10.46,13.87-25.71,24.65-42.88,27.27"/>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/necrogaia/pen/WVdEBg this is the codepen example that I'm using.

Comment: Seems to work fine here. We'll need something that actually demonstrates the problem in order to help you.

Comment: Obviously the problem is in your PHP code, not the animation.

Comment: Sorry, we don't debug websites. The moment you figure out how to fix it you'll do so and the question will be useless to anyone else.